# Maximum frequency of any mobile phone speaker

Tags: audio, mobile, frequency, speaker, speakerphone

I want to know , what is the maximum frequency of mobile speaker

look at this image :

[image: Human hearing is in acoustic area , between 20Hz and 20KHz]

I want to create and android application to generate sounds with particular frequency , but before that I want to know what frequencies can be generated by mobile phone speakers

what I really want to know is range of mobile phone speakers frequency  , and know whether can I generate infrasound  or ultrasound by mobile speakers , or any speaker.

sry for my bad english

Comment: I'm not aware of any API in Android or iOS that exposes specifications of the phone's built-in speaker hardware - such as its frequency response range - certainly it's going to vary widely. I guess the only way to find out is to play sounds with increasing frequency and hope the device's microphone will also pick it up and measure it yourself in-code (Fast-Fourier Transform ahoy!).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because there's nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1):

It varies widely, but most cellphones can not produce sounds over 20khz. Several go as high as 22khz, but that is it. So if you are looking to do repellent type things you will need more sophisticated equipment than a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at your purpose, but I think the answer might be more interesting in terms of how much energy at each frequency sub-range can a speakerphone produce.

You can play any frequency sound here: https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/

Try this on your phone, say around 75Hz, 200Hz and 1800Hz

I think speakerphone conversations sound tinny because the lower frequencies are lost and people crank up the volume to make up for it, and only the higher frequencies are audible at a distance.

On the high end of the range, you'll probably probably hit a hardware or software limit at 44kHz / some other high number.